# EDITED Can view the JSON response 200 OK but return parsererror

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, getjson

i can get the following string

```
([{"data":{"Rate":"","RoleA":"Student","NameA":"student","RoleB":"Tutor","NameB":"tutorB","Give":"0","Get":"1","Accept":"0"}}]);
```

i have read from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ but still not sure where did i do wrong.

this is my code

```
            $.ajax({
                        type:           'GET',
                        dataType:       'jsonp',
                        jsonpCallback:  'jsoncallback',
                        data: 
                        {

                                nameB:  nameB,
                                roleB:  roleB,
                                get123: get123,
                                accept: accept
                        },
                        url: 'http://mydomain.com/check.php?callback=?',
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data[0].data.RoleA);
                            //alert("ABC");
                            //if ( $("#role").text() == "Tutor" )
                            //{
                            //  window.location.href='tutor_home.html';
                            //}
                            //else
                            //{
                            //  window.location.href='student_home.html';
                            //}         
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                        }
            });
```

from chrome, i can find the json string, and it looks normal. however, it does not alert the success msg, instead it alert parsererror error..where should I change? Thanks

my php

```
<?php 

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-type: application/json");

include('mysqlConfig.php');


$nameB = $_GET["nameB"];
$roleB = $_GET["roleB"];
$get = $_GET["get123"];
$accept = $_GET["accept"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_rating WHERE NameB='$nameB' and RoleB='$roleB' and Get='$get' and Accept='$accept'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$rows = array();

//retrieve and print every record
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // $rows[] = $r; has the same effect, without the superfluous data attribute
    $rows[] = array('data' => $r);
}

// now all the rows have been fetched, it can be encoded
//echo json_encode($rows);

$data = json_encode($rows);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
?>
```

i am not sure why the URL is as follows
Request URL:
http://mydomain.com/check.php?callback=jsoncallback&nameB=tutorB&roleB=Tutor&get123=1&accept=0&_=1363710513593

the last parameter `&_=1363710513593` i am not sure what is it?

but it can return the above string

does it related to jquery version? i used jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: What did you try?  What errors did you encounter?  (Don’t expect us to do your homework for you...)

Comment: i have tried to change the type from GET to POST and tried to change different URL, and all of them both alert "There was an error."...

Comment: Can you show response from this link `http://mydomain.com/check.php?nameB=tutorB&roleB=Tutor&get123=1&accept=0&jsoncallback=mycallback`

Comment: @HUNG: Try to put a breakpoint on the alert, and check if the error function has no arguments.  Chances are there _is_ an argument, and that will probably contain more information about the specific error.

Comment: @vittore: yes I can. ([{"data":{"Rate":"","RoleA":"Student","NameA":"student","RoleB":"Tutor","NameB":"tutorB","Give":"0","Get":"1","Accept":"0"}}]);

Comment: @Martijn:  it alert parsererror error

Comment: @HUNG you see what is going on, you should've have `mycallback({....})` and it doesnt have callback name in response, so my client code is corresct. service is returning wrong data

Comment: it finally works. thanks all. it works when i change the URL from http://mydomain.com/check.php?callback=? to http://mydomain.com/check.php?jsoncallback=?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a callback name in the ajax settings object (right now its called "?"). Read more about how this works on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Lookup the "jsonp" in the settings object. You will also need to get that callback name in your PHP code and return it in the response so that that function will execute when it is being received to the client. 
Example: jsoncallback(YOURJSONDATA).

Pasted from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

jsonp
Type: String
Override the callback function name in a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the 'callback=?' part of the query string in the url. So {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in 'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

Comment: everything looks fine from the code after modified from above, but still cannot return success

Comment: I would need to get more information. Did you specify jsonp and  jsonpcallback? The the response still begin with the questionmark? Did the url contain the jsonpcallbackname that you specified? Might it be some kind of error in the backend?

Comment: i have updated in the post above, please let me know if u need further information =(

Comment: It looks like the response is missing the callback function name, so the error looks like its located in the PHP. It should look like this: jsoncallback([{"data":{"Rate":"","Ro...    I cannot write any fancy PHPH example because I come from the microsoft world and have never coded any PHP :-((((

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: you are showing that your service is not returning proper jsonp payload
Fix it to use passed callback name, so you'll have the following response, when you passing in `mycallback` as jsonp callback.

```
 mycallback([{"data":{"Rate":"","RoleA":"Student","NameA":"student","RoleB":"Tutor","NameB"‌​:"tutorB","Give":"0","Get":"1","Accept":"0"}}]);
```

UPDATED 2: `&_=1363710513593` - is timestamp added to request in order make jquery able to figure out what was corresponding jsonp request, because of the way how jsonp is handled on the client ( ie response comes as text and is embeded in the body )

json service you are accessing has support for jsonp , so you need to configure your `$.ajax` to do jsonp request and change json callback name to jsoncallback

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback : 'jsoncallback',
                data: 
                {

                        nameB:    nameB,
                        roleB:    roleB,
                        get123:   get123,
                        accept:   accept
                },
                url: 'http://mydomain.com/check.php',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data[0].data.RoleA);
                 }       
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
            });

            //return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is trying to reutnr jsonp. Try adding

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

to your ajax request and drop the jsoncallback=? paramter

e.g.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: 
                {

                        //nameB:    nameB,
                        //roleB:    roleB,
                        //get123:   get123,
                        //accept:   accept
                },
                url: 'http://mydomain.com/check.php?nameB=tutorB&roleB=Tutor&get123=1&accept=0&',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data[0].data.RoleA);     
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
            });

            //return false;
        });
```

Comment: you need to also set custom jsonCallback name in the request.